# jacoco afterEvaluate doesn't exclude directories

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

hi everybody i have a problem to exclude directories with the afterEvaluate, i don't understand how to write the directory's path.

i have the main project newPlatform with all subdirectories.this is the path of one of the folders to be excludednewPlatform -> backend -> src -> main -> java -> it.rete.pa.cons -> mapperi want all the classes inside the mapper folder to be excluded.how could i do it?thanks

i try this code with different attempts:

`afterEvaluate {`

`classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {`

`fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [`

`"retelit.paabs.consuntivazione/mapper/",`

`"src/main/java/retelit.paabs.consuntivazione/domain/dto/",`

`"src/main/java/retelit.paabs.consuntivazione/domain/enums",`

`"**/config/*"`

`])`

`}))`

`}`

`}`

could you help me to figure out?

thanks